# Erro ao cadastrar evento FullCalendar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Estou enfrentando um pequeno problema com o plugin FullCalendar, está acontecendo o seguinte.

Quando eu clico em uma data para gravar um determinado evento aparece um modal pra eu cadastrar, mas se eu sair sem salvar e clicar em outro dia ele salva 2 registros sendo um deles em branco e o que salva com os dados salva na data que eu tinha clicado anteriormente.

Já tentei retirar o evento submit de dentro da function select, porém nao obtive sucesso pois preciso das variaveis start e end que sao as datas a serem salvas no banco.

Se alguem puder me ajudar agradeço de coração.
Obrigado desde já

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var currentLangCode = 'pt-br';

   // build the language selector's options
   $.each($.fullCalendar.langs, function(langCode) {
    $('#lang-selector').append(
     $('<option/>')
      .attr('value', langCode)
      .prop('selected', langCode == currentLangCode)
      .text(langCode)
    );
   });

   // rerender the calendar when the selected option changes
   $('#lang-selector').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value) {
     currentLangCode = this.value;
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
     renderCalendar();
    }
   });

   function renderCalendar() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
     },
     defaultDate: Date(),
     selectable: true,
     selectHelper: true,
     unselectCancel: true,
     select: function(start, end) {
      $("#myModal").modal('show');
      //console.debug(start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
      //console.debug(end);
      $("#eventForm").on('submit',function() {
       var dados = $(this).serialize();
       $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "eventos.php",
                    data: dados+"&start="+start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")+"&end="+end.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
                    //dataType: 'json',
                    success: function( data )
                    {
                     console.log(data);
                     /*var eventData;
         if (data.title) {
          if (start.format("hh:mm:ss") == end.format("hh:mm:ss")) {
           eventData = {
            title: data.title,
            start: start.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            end: end.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            content: data.content
           };
          }else{
           eventData = {
            title: data.title,
            start: start,
            end: end,
            content: data.content
           };
          }
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
         }*/
         $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                    }
       });
       this.reset();
       $("#myModal").modal("hide");
       return false;
      });
      
     },
     eventClick: function(event) {
      $(this).popover({html:true,title:event.title,placement:'top',container:'body',content: event.content}).popover();
        },
     lang: currentLangCode,
     buttonIcons: false, // show the prev/next text
     weekNumbers: true,
     editable: false,
     eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
     events: {
      url: 'fullcalendar/demos/php/get-events.php',
     },
     loading: function(bool) {
      $('#loading').toggle(bool);
     }
    });
   }

   renderCalendar();
  });
```

Comment: Poste as partes importantes do seu código. Você pode ler [isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e depois [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/54944/edit) a pergunta.

Comment: Este é meu código, não entendo o por que ele manda as duas datas clicadas para o meu eventos.php. ai esta dando erro por que ele cadastra na data anterior que eu cliquei e salva outro registro em branco na data que era pra ser gravada

Comment: Ele está todo comentado por que estou fazendo testes e quando eu dou o console.log pra ver oq retorna do eventos na variavel start que eh a data de inicio volta as duas datas clicadas

Comment: Tenta tirar o evento submit do form de dentro do callback do select. Deixa só a abertura do modal lá dentro

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link http://jamelbaz.com/tutos/integration-de-fullcalendar2-php-mysql