# FullCalendar duplicando registro inserido no banco de dados

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

Estou utilizando o `fullCalendar` para fazer um cadastro de eventos.
Porém acontece o seguinte, se eu clico em um dia especifico aparece um modal com formulário para eu gravar os dados no banco de dados, até ai tudo bem ele insere no banco.
Mas se eu clicar em um dia do calendário e depois em outro qualquer que seja para depois eu cadastrar o evento ele cadastra os dados com a data do dia anterior que eu cliquei e gera um registro em branco com a outra data clicada.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz quanto a isto por favor?

Segue abaixo o código que estou usando:

OBS: já tentei retirar o evento submit do form de dentro do `select:function(){}` mas não funcionou pois preciso das variáveis que vem como parâmetro `(start,end)` que são as datas que são gravadas no banco.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentLangCode = 'pt-br';
    // build the language selector's options
    $.each($.fullCalendar.langs, function(langCode) {
        $('#lang-selector').append(
            $('<option/>')
            .attr('value', langCode)
            .prop('selected', langCode == currentLangCode)
            .text(langCode)
            );
    });

    // rerender the calendar when the selected option changes
    $('#lang-selector').on('change', function() {
        if (this.value) {
            currentLangCode = this.value;
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
            renderCalendar();
        }
    });

    function renderCalendar() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: Date(),
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: false,
            select: function(start, end) {
                $("#myModal").modal('show');
                $("#eventForm").on('submit',function() {
                    var dados = $(this).serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "eventos.php",
                        data: dados+"&start="+start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")+"&end="+end.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function( data )
                        {
                            console.log(data);
                            /*var eventData;
                            if (data.title) {
                                if (start.format("hh:mm:ss") == end.format("hh:mm:ss")) {
                                    eventData = {
                                        title: data.title,
                                        start: start.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                                        end: end.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                                        content: data.content
                                    };
                                }else{
                                    eventData = {
                                        title: data.title,
                                        start: start,
                                        end: end,
                                        content: data.content
                                    };
                                }
                                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                            }*/
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                        }
                    });
                    this.reset();
                    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                    return false;
                });
            },
            eventClick: function(event) {
                $(this).popover({html:true,title:event.title,placement:'top',container:'body',content: event.content}).popover();
            },
            lang: currentLangCode,
            buttonIcons: false, // show the prev/next text
            weekNumbers: true,
            editable: false,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: {
                url: 'fullcalendar/demos/php/get-events.php',
            },
            loading: function(bool) {
                $('#loading').toggle(bool);
            }
        });
    }
    renderCalendar();
});
```

Comment: Porque vc cadastrou outra pergunta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54944/erro-ao-cadastrar-evento-fullcalendar

Comment: Por que nao conseguia comentar na pergunta anterior, ficava aparecendo uma mensagem de que precisava de pontos e como sou recem cadastrado aqui, nao entendo ainda como funciona o forum nesta questao de pontos

Comment: Eu ainda acho que o problema é esse evento submit. Já que vc precisa dos parâmetros, tenta salvá-los em um campo hidden no form logo antes de abrir a modal. Daí na hora de submeter, vc pega o valor desses campos.

Comment: Lucas, deu certo o que vc falou, eu pego agora e passo sempre os valores pro form e ai eu consigo salvar corretamente, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Que bom. Vou adicionar uma resposta

Comment: Você pode aceitar a resposta. [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)

Answer (score 1):

O problema é o fato de o evento `submit` estar dentro do evento `select`. Assim ele vai criar várias chamadas conforme vai clicando no calendário.

Remova todo o `$("#eventForm").on('submit',function() { ...` de dentro do `select`. Crie 2 campos `input type="hidden"` no form e, antes de abrir a modal, salve o `start` e o `end` nesses campos. Quando submeter o form, os valores serão enviados.